# {'field': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')] - DJANGO REST FRAMEWORK

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to parse the JSON  data nad import it to the database through API. I think I almost got it but still getting this message: `{'field': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]` from my HttpResponse and I don't really know what to do with it.

Here is my code:

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Data(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    eid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=0, blank=False)
    data = models.TextField(max_length=800, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "ID: {} -- Name: {}".format(self.eid, self.name)
```

serializers.py

I honestly think that the problem is in the serializers but can't figure it out what to add here.

```
from .models import Data
from rest_framework import serializers

class DataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Data
        fields = ['name', 'eid', 'data']

class DetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Data
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

Here I must have 3 views. First for Import. Second for show basic data like name, id, etc. which are given from the JSON file I provide to `import/` API. And third for full details of the data given from the JSON file.

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponse
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, authentication_classes, permission_classes
from rest_framework.exceptions import ParseError
from rest_framework.authentication import BasicAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from .serializers import DataSerializer, DetailSerializer
from .models import Data

@csrf_exempt            
@api_view(['POST'])     
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])  
@authentication_classes([BasicAuthentication])  
#IMPORT VIEW
def import_data(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            data = JSONParser().parse(request) 
            serializer = DataSerializer(data=data, many=True) 
            serializer.is_valid() 
        except ParseError: 
            return JsonResponse({"detail":"DATA YOU IMPORTED ARE NOT JSON DATA"}, safe=False, status=400)
        except KeyError:
            return JsonResponse({"detail":"NAME AND ID MUST BE INCLUDED"}, safe=False, status=400)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False, status=201)
        else:
            return HttpResponse(serializer.errors)
    else:
        return JsonResponse({"detail":"ACCEPTING ONLY POST REQUESTS"}, safe=False, status=400)        


@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['GET'])
def data_view(request, name):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        data = Data.objects.filter(name__iexact=name)
        if data:
            serializer = DataSerializer(data, many=True)
            serializer.is_valid()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False, status=200)
        else:
            return JsonResponse({"detail":"NO DATA FOUND"}, safe=False, status=404)
    else:
        return JsonResponse({"detail":"ACCEPTING ONLY GET REQUESTS"}, safe=False, status=400)    

@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['GET'])
def data_details(request, name, eid):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        data = Data.objects.filter(name__iexact=name, eid=eid)
        if data:
            serializer = DetailSerializer(data['eid'], many=False)
            # serializer.is_valid()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=200)
        else:
            return JsonResponse({"details":"DATA NOT FOUND"}, safe=False, status=404)
    else:
        return JsonResponse({"details":"ACCEPTING ONLY GET REQUESTS"}, safe=False, status=400)
```

Thank you for any help <3.

Comment: Use `django-cors-headers` instead of `csrf_exempt`

Comment: Should show the content of your post data

Comment: Well, it means the field in question is required. Tried just passing a value for that field?

Comment: Well it's a task when I have to pass certain data which were given to me. So I can't change it to the way I want it if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

A sample for class view:

```py
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView


class ImportDataView(APIView): 
    queryset = Data.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DataSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    authentication_classes = (BasicAuthentication,)
  
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)


import_data = ImportDataView.as_view()
```

Comment: When I added it, it shows me this error: View.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given.